# How to Write back to Parent's pipe?

Tags: c++, c, fork, posix

Assume I have the following code. Is it possible to write from the child back to the parent? Can I do it through the same pipe, **mypipe?** Do I need another wait function?

```
int mypipe[2];
int i, pid;

pipe (mypipe);
value = fork ();
if (value == -1)
  {
    exit (0);
  }
else if (value == 0)
  {
    read (mypipe[0], (char *) &i, sizeof (int));
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;
    exit (0);
  }
else
  {
    i = 7;
    write (mypipe[1], (char *) &i, sizeof (int));
    wait (&pid);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are unidirectional. There is one write end and one read end. If you have multiple processes (child and parent) reading the pipe, it is undefined what messages will be read by each.

Yes, the child could write to the (normally parent-to-child pipe) but if it then turns around and reads again from the pipe, before the parent can, it will read its own message!

Your best bet is to either use a pair of pipes (one in each direction) or a PF_LOCAL socket connection which is bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can either use the pipe so that the parent writes and the child reads, or so that the child writes and the parent reads. Pipes are unidirectional though, so you cannot do both (if you want to do both, you would want a `socketpair`).

From the manpage:

> `pipe()` creates  a  pipe,  a unidirectional data channel that can be used for interprocess communication. The array `pipefd` is used to return two file descriptors referring to the ends of the pipe. `pipefd[0]`  refers to the *read* end  of the pipe. `pipefd[1]` refers to the *write* end of the pipe. Data written to the write end of the pipe is buffered by the kernel until it is read from the read end of the pipe. For further  details, see `pipe(7)`.

I've cleared your program up and made it compile in C (no `cout`), and it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int mypipe[2];
int i, pid;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int value;
  pipe (mypipe);
  value = fork ();
  if (value == -1)
    {
      perror ("Cannot fork");
      exit (1);
    }
  else if (value == 0)
    {
      read (mypipe[0], &i, sizeof (int));
      printf ("i = %d\n", i);
      wait (&pid);
      exit (0);
    }
  else
    {
      i = 7;
      write (mypipe[1], &i, sizeof (int));
      exit (0);
    }
}
```

As you can see there were no major changes (save that for some reason you were trying to write an int using a `char` pointer which on a little-endian machine is going to write a 0).

Your program reads in child and writes in the parent.

Here's a version that reads in the parent and writes in the child, that also works fine. As you can see it's just a matter of swapping the read and write bits around.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int mypipe[2];
int i, pid;

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int value;
  pipe (mypipe);
  value = fork ();
  if (value == -1)
    {
      perror ("Cannot fork");
      exit (0);
    }
  else if (value == 0)
    {
      i = 7;
      write (mypipe[1], &i, sizeof (int));
      exit (0);
    }
  else
    {
      read (mypipe[0], &i, sizeof (int));
      printf ("i = %d\n", i);
      wait (&pid);
      exit (0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't `wait()` in the child process for the parent to die. In Unix systems, parents can wait for their children to die, but not vice versa.

Comment: Oops - I swapped too much there, and have put the `wait` back into the parent. The test case worked because the `read` would not complete before the `write` was done anyway.

Comment: It worked because the `wait()` would return immediately with ECHILD (your child process had no children of its own).  But, as you said, it worked fine.

Comment: Yup, I meant the pipe worked. You are obviously correct as to why `wait` did not hang. Anyway, now fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you control the synchronization between the two processes somehow, you can use a single pipe to write from parent to child and from child to parent.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int mypipe[2];
    int i, pid;
    pipe(mypipe);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("Cannot fork");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        read(mypipe[0], &i, sizeof(int));
        printf("child: i = %d\n", i);
        i += 13;
        write(mypipe[1], &i, sizeof(int));
    }
    else
    {
        i = 7;
        write(mypipe[1], &i, sizeof(int));
        int status;
        int corpse = wait(&status);
        read(mypipe[0], &i, sizeof(int));
        printf("parent: i = %d (child = %d = %d; status = 0x%.4X)\n",
               i, pid, corpse, status);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run:

```
child: i = 7
parent: i = 20 (child = 62299 = 62299; status = 0x0000)
```

The synchronization here is that the parent process waits for the child to die before reading the suicide note from the child.

This is seldom used — you normally create two separate pipes, one for the parent to write to the child and the other for the child to write to the parent — because it simplifies the synchronization.  The only issue you have to be careful of is not filling the pipes so that the parent is blocked trying to write to the child while the child is blocked trying to write to the parent (deadlock).  If you have a simple half-duplex protocol (so that each process knows when the other has finished its current message), or if you have separate reader and writer threads in each process, you can avoid deadlock.

Note that some systems ([BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pipe)) provide bidirectional pipes.  Sockets are bidirectional communication channels too.